# Ansible sudo su - user privilege escalation issue

Tags: ansible, sudo, su

My Environment uses work with Linux environments.

My Login process is
1. login to Linux box using my personal ID.
2. then switch to application id ==> sudo su - applicationID
[this switch does not ask a password and takes me to the home domain_path for applicationID]
3. All tasks are performed here.

Can i implement the same switch through Ansible.
Tried become, become_user and also remote_user nothing works
I am getting multiple errors and not sure how to get thru.
It also asks me for a password which i do not have.
Saw multiple posts but cant understand the combination of sudo su - userID

Comment: In ansible you can [become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) a user.

Comment: tried but did not work as below:
become_user: app_id
become: true
become_exe: "sudo su -"

Comment: Can you please add the errors you are getting?

Comment: Tried as su and sudo
FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}
OR

FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chown: invalid user: ‘appid’\n}). For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}

Comment: Is your user app_id or appid? The error says invalid user. Try looking into that.

Comment: there is only one  id, for mentioning it here i used as an example app_id.

Comment: Error: FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: \r\nWe trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System\r\nAdministrator. It usually boils down to these three things:\r\n\r\n    #1) Respect the privacy of others.\r\n    #2) Think before you type.\r\n    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.\r\n\r\n"}

Comment: So it does work, It's waiting for a password. Either specify the become_pass or use expect to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
- hosts: application
  become: yes
  become_exe: "sudo su - applicationID"
  become_method: su
  tasks:
```